# How to serialize default values in nested messages in Protobuf

Tags: python, json, dictionary, protocol-buffers, protobuf-3

As the title states I have a protobuf message with another message inside it like this:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message Message
{
    message SubMessage {
        int32 number = 1;
    }
    
    SubMessage subMessage = 1;
}
```

My `example.json` is empty (which means default values everywhere):

```json
{
}
```

In my python script I read this message with:

```py
example_json = open("example.json", "r").read()

example_message = example.Message()
google.protobuf.json_format.Parse(example_json, example_message)
```

and when I check the value of `example_message.subMessage.number` it is `0` which is correct.

Now I want to convert it into a dict where *all* values are present - even the default values.
For the conversion I use the method `google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToDict()`.
But as you may know `MessageToDict()` doesn't serialize default values without me telling it to do so (like in this question: [Protobuf doesn't serialize default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021797/protobuf-doesnt-serialize-default-values/)).
So I added the argument `including_default_value_fields=True` to the call of `MessageToDict()`:

```py
protobuf.MessageToDict(example_message, including_default_value_fields=True)
```

which returns:

```py
{}
```

instead of what I expected:

```py
{'subMessage': {'number': 0}}
```

A comment in the code of protobuf (found here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py) confirms this behaviour:

> including_default_value_fields: If True, singular primitive fields,
> repeated fields, and map fields will always be serialized.  If
> False, only serialize non-empty fields.  Singular message fields
> and oneof fields are not affected by this option.

So what can I do to get a dict with *all* values even when they are default values inside nested messages?

---

Interestingly when my `example.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "subMessage" : {
        "number" : 0
    }
}
```

I get the expected output.
But I cannot make sure that the `example.json` will have all values written out so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of [Looping over Protocol Buffers attributes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148391/looping-over-protocol-buffers-attributes-in-python/29150312) I created a custom `MessageToDict` function:

```py
def MessageToDict(message):
    message_dict = {}
    
    for descriptor in message.DESCRIPTOR.fields:
        key = descriptor.name
        value = getattr(message, descriptor.name)
        
        if descriptor.label == descriptor.LABEL_REPEATED:
            message_list = []
            
            for sub_message in value:
                if descriptor.type == descriptor.TYPE_MESSAGE:
                    message_list.append(MessageToDict(sub_message))
                else:
                    message_list.append(sub_message)
            
            message_dict[key] = message_list
        else:
            if descriptor.type == descriptor.TYPE_MESSAGE:
                message_dict[key] = MessageToDict(value)
            else:
                message_dict[key] = value
    
    return message_dict
```

Given the message read from the empty `example.json` this function returns:

```json
{'subMessage': {'number': 0}}
```